# Change title of UITableView to a cell name in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with some rows that are allocated dynamically. When I tap on a row I will go to another TableView using a push Segue, how do I change the second table view title to the cell name of the first table view cell that was tapped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the following code inside **tableViewDidSelectRowAtIndexPath** method

```
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *title=cell.textLabel.text;
```

Now you can pass the string ***title*** to the next table view.

Comment: I tried this and passed the title in the prepareForSegue but the title doesn't change immediately, it changes after i go back to the first table and tap on the cell again

Answer (score 0):

I made a string where i stored the cell title in **tabeViewDidSelectRowAtIndexPath** and I passed it in the **prepareForSegue** but the title string but when I tapped on the cell the first method to be called was **prepareForSegue** and the string would get instantiated after that so i called

> [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"nameOfSegue" sender: self];

in **tabeViewDidSelectRowAtIndexPath** and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In swift try

```
    let selectedCell = self.SomeTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? SomeTableViewCell
    if let cell = selectedCell {
        // get text from cell label for example
    }
```